# Closed. This question needs to be more focused -> reopen

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I have asked the question [counting number of steps to reduce integer to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861252/counting-number-of-steps-to-reduce-integer-to-0) which to be fair was broad, thus it got closed, and got this message:

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently
> accepting answers.
>
> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help
> others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new
> one.

I was advised to edit the question to focus is more, which I did. How do I know if I edited correctly to reopen the question?

Comment: You could add a link to it here and ask for advise or simply wait. Your edit pushed the question to the reopen queue to be reviewed by others. If they will find your edit sufficient, it will be reopened

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have added the link to the question, sorry I forgot to do that, thank you

Comment: Can you please also explain what you want to achieve with re-opening the question? There is an accepted answer - you probably should un-accept it and comment why it does not apply to the question since you need *different* answers based on this request.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes I have an accepted answer. But this is just rather just a query for future question. also the question has ah crossed eye symbol, does it mean the question is also hidden?

Comment: It’s not the question that’s hidden, it’s the specifics of the close reason. If you open your question while not logged in (like in a private window), the text next to that symbol isn’t visible.

Comment: Don't edit a post in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.

Comment: @philipxy I tried to focus on where the problem originates, rather than just saying there is a problem.